# .save() doesn't work on Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I want to broadcast a notification to all users in one of my services, notifications are array attribute of user model.
so I should push object of new notification to every user notification array in database.
here is my code:

```js
broadcastNotif : function (notif) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      User.find().exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        else {
          while (users.length>0) {
            var user = users.pop();
            if (user.notifications==undefined)
              user.notifications=[];
            user.notifications.push({
              type : notif.type,
              title : notif.title,
              link : notif.link,
              date : notif.date
            });
            sails.log(user);
            user.save(function (err) {
              if (err) return reject(err);
            })
          }
          return resolve();
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

`sails.log(user)` print correct objects in console but when I check my mongo Database found nothing saved there, they are all unchanged.

what's wrong with `user.save()`?!

Comment: What does your `User` model look like?

Comment: @Fissio this is my User model:
[link](https://github.com/AliKarami/labRiver/blob/master/api/models/User.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I found sails doesn't support array attributes like this in models:

```
notifications : [
  {
    type : {
      type : 'string',
      defaultsTo : 'general'
    },
    title : {
      type : 'string',
      required : true
    },
    link : {
      type : 'string'
    },
    date : {
      type : 'datetime',
      defaultsTo: new Date().toISOString()
    }
  }
]
```

and I forced to change my notifications attribute to:

```
notifications : {
  type : 'array'
}
```

and check and validate everything manually :(